# What is this MPU?

Tags: identification, programming, cpu

I have a board model `SWL-B70F`, it's a wifi module used in Samsung AC. This board ship an "unknown" MPU, 256 Mbit DRAM ([`W948D6FBHX6E`](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w948dxfb_datasheet_pkg_a01-004_20121015.pdf)), 128Mbit Serial Flash memory ([`25Q128FVSG`](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25q128fv_revhh1_100913_website1.pdf)), a wifi module ([`BCM43143KMLG`](https://www.cypress.com/file/298756/download)). The [`Ar18hsfnbwkneu` Service Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/834628/Samsung-Ar18hsfnbwkneu.html?page=68#manual) contains the block diagram below. On the top there is a row of 11 pin connected to the MPU, and on the bottom a double row of 14 pins also connected to the MPU (I suspect it to be JTAG port).

As a starting point, I would like to be able to execute on this board a simple "Hello world" program, then in the future more complex things using the wifi. But I can't find documentation for this CPU.

Does anyone knows about it? May I expect to find appropriate SDK, tool chain for it?

Thanks

[image: CLM5510 ARM]
[image]

Comment: the development team knows about it ... you may expect to find the SDK, if you wish ... whether your expectation gets fulfilled is another story .... perhaps you could ask a technical question

Comment: It may be a custom part number made specifically for that application.

Comment: Why do you want to write software for an air conditioner?

Comment: @David the software on it is very crappy and unmaintained. This connected thing is only providing some old XML API, usable officially with a really old android app that even doesn't support complex wifi password. It also doesn't provide a web interface, which is the minimum I expect for such things. And BTW, everyone is free to do what he wants ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some detective work, I can give you some steps towards an answer but not a *full* answer. Perhaps you (or someone else) can build on this.

> Does anyone knows about it?

That logo is from "Core Logic" in South Korea (i.e. Corelogic Co. Ltd., who don't seem to be related to any other company of a similar name) so not a surprise that Samsung chose to use them. This also explains the "CL" prefix to the device part number `CLM5510`.

The date code of the device shown in your photo is probably 23rd week of 2015, so that device is around 5 years old. A dead link (explained below) also mentions a 2012 date for that range of devices.

The company "Core Logic Co. Ltd." merged with (took over?) the South Korean company "Comed Life Sciences Co. Ltd." in 2017 and "pivoted" into a Bio / Pharma company. The original company website - http://www.corelogic.co.kr - was abandoned in late 2017 (it now shows a "parking page" saying it is for sale by a domain name registrar) then the merged company rebranded to "Synergy Innovation" also in 2017. For a while, starting in 2018 and finishing some time later, the original Core Logic website redirected to http://www.synergyinno.com. That website redirection eventually lapsed. (http://www.synergyinno.com is still the live site for the merged Bio / Pharma company.)

I found a distributor of the old Core Logic devices, including the CLM5510, and [this](http://www.aoelectronics.com/en/manufacturers-detail.php?tnid=156) webpage includes a (dead) link which claims to be to the datasheet of the CLM5510. From the (misspelled) name in the dead link - http://www.corelogic.co.kr/down_pb/Hwak_Feb2012.pdf - it seems that the CLM5510 was part of Core Logic's "Hawk" range of devices, which is described on that distributor's webpage as:

> Hawk is an ARM9 based processor optimised for Mobile TV and small multimedia players with full support for various worldwide Mobile TV standards (ISDB-T 1-seg, ATSC-M/H, CMMB).

So that's it. **In summary**: The original manufacturer was "Core Logic" in South Korea, but that company doesn't seem to exist after 2017. If you can find any information about their "Hawk" range of devices, that distributor suggests your device is from that range. I couldn't find a working link to any SDK or other technical information for your device.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detective work! So I'll cannot do anything with it, I'll put it in a box for the next years and forgive about it…